# Immunity Debugger: Giving names to variables and addresses

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

When working with Immunity Debugger, I have to deal with a lot of addresses of the form "ESP+x", which gets quite tricky as more and more calls get nested.

Is there a way to choose names for such addresses, so I'll be able to track them even within nested calls? (Of course such feature will also be useful if everything happens within one scope.)